# How do I Import email from Thunderbird Snap 86.0b3 to Thunderbird 68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Tags: email, thunderbird

I used Ubuntu Software to remove Thunderbird Snap 86.0b3 and install Thunderbird Mail 68.10.0
I am running Thunderbird Mail on Ubuntu 18.04.
Unfortunately I removed Thunderbird Snap before I installed Thunderbird Mail.
My deja-dup backup had done a complete backup earlier that day.
I used deja-dup to restore Thunderbird Snap files and folders to: /home/rob/snap/thunderbird.
Thunderbird Mail imported everything in the Address Book with no problem.
Thunderbird Mail import says "No application to import data from found." when I try to import all my locally saved emails.
Thunderbird Snap stored the emails I want in: 3evxk23j.default.
I copied the 3evxk23j.default folder to /home/rob/.cache/thunderbird thinking maybe Thunderbird would recognize it. It did not.
Can anyone tell me how I can get Thunderbird Mail to import the files from Thunderbird Snap into Thunderbird Mail? Thank you.